# Google Maps API Keys - Browser/Server

Tags: php, api, google-maps

I am using Google Maps Key to geo-code an Address. In my local machine I have used the browser Key. It geo coded the address correctly. Then I moved my code to Production. In Production Addresses are geo coded to 0.00000 lat and 0.00000 lon.

There are no code diff.

Is there any thing I can do with the Server and Browser Keys?

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something is obviously different, otherwise the results would be the same. Review your code - line by line if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments and thanks for the Minus (-) points given.

I figure out the problem.

1. From Google Browser & Server Keys works.
2. The error was totally on MySQL side. I set LAT column to be float and it it NULL able. And when GeoCoding I check those columns are NULL. But in the other sever the default was not taken as NULL but as 0 (zero). Since NULL != 0 it was not geocoded.

Tip: I could find this after I implement a log table, which logs every call to Google Maps that I do.

Hope my answer help anyone who stuck with this kind of an error.

Thanks